# Issue deploying a Deno Fresh app using new ahead-of-time builds and GitHub actions

Tags: typescript, github-actions, deno, deno-deploy

I'm trying to deploy my Fresh app using the new ahead-of-time builds to pre-optimize static assets. I've followed the instructions on the [docs site](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/concepts/ahead-of-time-builds) and it works just fine locally.

However, when trying to deploy on Deno Deploy, the deploy workflow fails on the Build step (when running `deno task build`).

The reason is the following error:

`error: The source code is invalid, as it does not match the expected hash in the lock file. Specifier: https://esm.sh/preact@10.15.1/debug`.

I've been doing some research, and it seems that **esm.sh** import `preact` dependencies using different build versions which in turn fails integrity check, and the proposed solution is pinning the versions on `deno.json`, however, it doesn't work for me or, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the relevant part of my `deno.json` file imports:

```
"imports": {
  "preact": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.15.1?pin=v122",
  "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.15.1/",
  "preact-render-to-string": "https://esm.sh/*preact-render-to-string@6.2.1?pin=v122",
  "@preact/signals": "https://esm.sh/*@preact/signals@1.1.3",
  "@preact/signals-core": "https://esm.sh/*@preact/signals-core@1.2.3",
}
```

This is the build task command:

```
deno run -A dev.ts build --lock=deno.lock --lock-write
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. I deleted the lockfile and restarted the service to generate a new lock file.